# Find NON-duplicate column value combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is for a migration script.

CompanyTable:

| EmployeeId | DivisionId |
| --- | --- |
| abc | div1 |
| def | div1 |
| abc | div1 |
| abc | div2 |
| xyz | div2 |

In the below code I am Selecting duplicate EmployeeId-DivisionId combinations, that is, the records that have the same EmployeeId and DivisionId will be selected. So from the above table, the two rows that have `abc-div1` combination will be selected by the below code.

How can I invert it? It seems so simple but I can't figure it out. I tried replacing with `HAVING count(*) = 0` instead of  `> 1`, I've tried fiddling with the equality signs in the ON and AND lines. Basically from the above table, I want to select the other three rows that **don't** have the `abc-div1` combination. If there is a way to select all the unique EmployeeID-DivisionId combinations, let me know.

```
SELECT a.EmployeeID, a.DivisionId FROM CompanyTable a
  JOIN ( SELECT EmployeeID, DivisionId 
         FROM CompanyTable 
         GROUP BY EmployeeID, DivisionId 
         HAVING count(*) > 1 ) b
    ON a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
   AND a.DivisionId = b.DivisionId;
```

EmployeeId and DivisionId are both nvarchar(50) columns.

Comment: The opposite of > 1 is <=1, not = 0. Maybe this is already the answer. If not, you should please provide data structure, sample data and required result, please.

Comment: @JonasMetzler - Thanks, added a table, and what I expect.

Comment: @Stu - Ah sorry I didn't know. Marking the answers I accepted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, you must replace > 1 by its real opposite <= 1, this works: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a79dcbd922ecd84c07929ad1ad46949f)

Answer (score 2):

A windowed count would seem a suitable method:

```
select employeeid, divisionid
from (
    select *, Count(*) over(partition by employeeid, divisionid) ct
    from t
)t
where ct = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's try rewriting your query using a common table expression (CTE), instead of a subquery:

```
WITH cteCompanyTableStats as (
    SELECT 
        EmployeeID, DivisionId, 
        HasDuplicates = CASE WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM CompanyTable 
    GROUP BY EmployeeID, DivisionId 
)
SELECT ct.*
FROM CompanyTable ct
    inner join cteCompanyTableStats cts on
        ct.EmployeeId = cts.EmployeeId 
        and ct.DivisionId = cts.DivisionId
        and cts.HasDuplicates = 1
```

Notice how I've removed the `HAVING` clause & added a new `HasDuplicates` column?  We're going to use that new column to find all of the table rows that *-DON'T-* have duplicates:

```
WITH cteCompanyTableStats as (
    SELECT 
        EmployeeID, DivisionId, 
        HasDuplicates = CASE WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM CompanyTable 
    GROUP BY EmployeeID, DivisionId 
)
SELECT ct.*
FROM CompanyTable ct
    inner join cteCompanyTableStats cts on
        ct.EmployeeId = cts.EmployeeId 
        and ct.DivisionId = cts.DivisionId
        and cts.HasDuplicates = 0
```

The only character of SQL code that changed between the two queries was the last line, where `and cts.HasDuplicates = ###` is set.